# How do I get a header with a python web scraper?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so I am having an issue with a web scraper I am making for a website I'm developing. The main issue I am having is when trying to get a header for a product that is in an h1 format, it keeps responding with this:
`<h1 class="product-detail__title small-title">CHERRY MX SILENT RED(10pcs)</h1>`
I just want the Cherry Mx Silent Red part and not all of the other stuff.
Here is the code for my web scraper:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://kbdfans.com/collections/cherry-switches/products/cherry-mx-silent-red'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h1', {'class' : 'product-detail__title small-title'})

print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
title.get_text()
```

Your title is not a string, it's an object

From BeautifulSoup documentation:

> `The find_all() method looks through a tag’s descendants and retrieves all descendants that match your filters.`

For your *title* variable, you may refer to bs4.element.Tag documentation, and if you have a doubt you can always print all available methods of that object like this:

```py
print(dir(title))
```

Comment: Is this correct? ```title = soup.get_text('h1', {'class' : 'product-detail__title.small-title'})```

Comment: Code you shared in your question is allright, you just have to call get_text() function on your title object, and it does not require any argument, just change your last print by this: "print(title.get_text())"
More documentation here on get_text: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: alrighty, so this is the result i got ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\redoc\Documents\GitHub\KeeBuilderRepo\webscraper.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(title.get_text())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_text'```

Comment: Mm works for me, what is your Beautiful soup version ?

Comment: How can i find it?

Comment: @MrSirDolphin Replace your last line with this - ```print(title.get_text())```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the text from your `<h1>` just use `.text` and `.get_text()` when you need to pass custom arguments to `strip` whitespaces,... or add an seperator (e.g. `title.get_text(strip=True, seperator=',')`).

```
print(title.text)
```

or

```
print(title.get_text())
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://kbdfans.com/collections/cherry-switches/products/cherry-mx-silent-red'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h1', {'class' : 'product-detail__title small-title'})

print(title.text)
```

#### Output

```
CHERRY MX SILENT RED(10pcs)
```